# How to make a pthread signal another that it can continue executing?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I have three integers (a, b and c), and I'd like to create two threads (**POSIX pthreads**) to access them in this particular sequence to keep the results consistent:

```
Thread 1  |  Thread 2
---------------------
a=1          b=5
c=7
             c=c+10
             b=a+c*2
a=b+b*10
```

That is, c=c+10 in thread2 must wait until c=7 in thread1 finishes. Also a=b+b*10 in thread1 must wait until b=a+c*2 in thread2 finished.

I have tried using mutexes, but it does not work as I intend (code below). If thread2 starts first, it can lock mutex1 before thread1 has locked it, so the sequencing is lost. Locking the mutex from the main thread is not an option, as it would yield an undefined behavior (mutex locked and then unlocked by a different thread). I've also tried using conditional variables, but a similar problem arises: a signal can happen before the associated wait.

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int a, b, c;
pthread_mutex_t mutex1, mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *thread1(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    a = 1;
    c = 7; 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    a = b + b*10; 
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *thread2(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    b = 5;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    c = c + 10;
    b = a + c*2;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t t1, t2;

    if(pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread1, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating Thread 1\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread2, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating Thread 2\n");
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    return a;
}
```

My question is, what is correct way to achieve the thread sequencing I want using pthreads? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't these `int a, b, c;` variables be volatile?

Comment: @usr I simplified the code here, the real code has bigger chunks that execute in parallel

Comment: Without even looking in depth, 2 mutexes for one synchronisation job seem fishy.

Comment: The usual: a) serializing two threads is pointless b) Mutex is the wrong synchro for this, and I don't uderstand why so may peple keep trying it - it still doesn't work, every time.  c)  Use two semaphores.  Swap around one 'execution permit' between the threads.

Comment: You might want to read wikipedia's [barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)) article.

Comment: @MartinJames thanks, the semaphores seems to be the solution

Comment: @spectras thanks, I considered using barriers, but they are not implemented in the OSX implementation of pthreads for example

Comment: @JuanMRivas> it's not something provided, it's a concept/algorithm that you can implement to block multiple threads until they have all reached a specific point. (be careful not to confuse with "memory barrier" by the way, they share nothing but the word itself)

Comment: @usr Thanks for the link. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex1, mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER
```

Only initializes the second one; but that is a nit.  Depending upon the system you are running, you might not notice this, because mutex1 is uninitialized, thus the operations on it may be failing, or the initializer constant could be zero....

The signal/wait problem is not a problem -- you wait upon a condition protected by a mutex, in this pattern:

```
lock();
while (check() == false) {
    wait();
}
func();
signal();
unlock();
```

so thread1’s check would be true, and func would be c = 7
while thread2’s check would be (c == 7) and func would be c += 10